Deeplearning4j. The problem of obtaining predictions from incoming parameters
I use SpringBoot and the Deeplearning4j library.
Using the example from https://www.baeldung.com/deeplearning4j I created a project in which I created a trained model.
When tested, the model shows good prediction statistics
Examples labeled as 0 classified by model as 0: 19 times
Examples labeled as 1 classified by model as 1: 16 times
Examples labeled as 1 classified by model as 2: 3 times
Examples labeled as 2 classified by model as 2: 15 times

==========================Scores========================================
 # of classes:    3
 Accuracy:        0,9434
 Precision:       0,9444
 Recall:          0,9474
 F1 Score:        0,9411
Precision, recall & F1: macro-averaged (equally weighted avg. of 3 classes)

Unfortunately, when manually testing model (saved before) on incoming data, it most often works incorrectly.
Although I take the data examples from the same file as originally
String[] values = param.split(",");
double[] data = new double[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
}
INDArray input = multiLayerNetwork.output(Nd4j.create(data));
return input.toString();

For example, I pass 5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2 and it correctly determines [0.98, 0.02, 0.00] (i.e. 1 class), when I pass 6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8 it correctly determines [0.00, 0.00, 1.00] (i.e. 3rd class), but no matter what I transfer from 2nd class always comes [0.00, 0.00, 1.00] (i.e. 3rd class)
Examples for training https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/deeplearning4j/src/main/resources/iris.txt
I want the trained model to be able to predict values from the input parameters, what am I doing wrong?
